# Linux Mint: make a "public clickable launcher" from a sh root only?

Tags: shell, shell-script, files, root

I made a shell script to install packages, configure them, etc.

Usually I run it via Terminal `sudo sh gizmo.sh`

Now I aim to put it in a double-clickable file to run it, for any user (no sudo, so su to do before). Is that possible ?

"Simply" like a .exe file, or innoSetup installer on Windows, or PackageMaker on OSX...

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy if you're willing to use `gksu` or similar; they just give you a pretty GUI way to enter the password like you do with `sudo`. Otherwise, you could edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow anyone to run it without a password, then have a double-clickable shell script that contains `sudo gizmo.sh`.